# How to adjust the options box in Amazon Mechanical Turk's <crowd-form> template

Tags: javascript, html, css, mturk

I am using the following code, where the array of categories are created in random order using javascript and passed into 's "categories" property as an array.

I am wondering if there is any way to adjust the presentation of the 18 options such that I have my 18 options appearing all at once (perhaps 9 in a column, and another 9 in another column), rather than having the mturk worker to scroll up and down. Is there any code for that?

This is what my current layout with a scroll button looks like now and I have the code written below.

[image]

```
<crowd-image-classifier

src="${image_url}"

header="What occupation do you think this person belongs to?"

name = "occupation"

id = "occupation">



<!-- Use the short-instructions section for quick instructions that the Worker will see while working on the task. Including some basic examples of good and bad answers here can help get good results. You can include any HTML here. -->

<short-instructions>

<p>Please select one occupation that this person could conceivably belong to.</p>

<p></p>

</short-instructions>



<!-- Use the full-instructions section for more detailed instructions that the Worker can open while working on the task. Including more detailed instructions and additional examples of good and bad answers here can help get good results. You can include any HTML here. -->

<full-instructions header="Classification Instructions">

<p>Please select one occupation that this person could conceivably belong to.</p>

<p></p>

</full-instructions>



</crowd-image-classifier>
```

I already tried adding a style element at the top like but it couldn't recognize the #occupation id at all or change anything

```
<style>
#occupation {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML of the actual dropdown menu?

Comment: I am trying to find it, but I am not sure where it is contained. Here is the top part of the html file that might provide some clues:


<!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<!-- For the full list of available Crowd HTML Elements and their input/output documentation,
      please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-reference.html -->